# Remove extra line break from a variable

Tags: linux, command

[image]

I am writing a script where I am trying to export some variable , and after exporting my variable when I am printing, it is printing an extra line after it.

Here I am reading from a csv file containing two columns.
This script is present in file script.sh and I am executing that file ./script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read f1 f2
do
      echo "Source IP        : $f1"     #it is printing without extra line
      echo "Destination IP   : $f2"               #it is printing without extra line  

    export sourceIP=$f1
    export destIP=$f2

    ssh -t -t sjain@$f1 <<ENDSSH
    #Start copying 33KB File
    echo "Destination IP Address: $destIP" # here it is printing an extra line after destIP
    startTime=$(($(date '+%s%N')/1000000))
    scp KB_33.txt sjain@$destIP:/home/sjain
    endTime=$(($(date '+%s%N')/1000000))
    printf 'Elapsed time in copying 33KB file: %s\n' $((endTime-startTime)) 
    #Write the stats to the file
    echo $sourceIP','$destIP',33KB,'$((endTime-startTime)) >> report.txt
    exit
    ENDSSH
done < ipaddress.csv
```

because of the above problem when I am executing

```
scp KB_33.txt sjain@$destIP:/home/sjain
```

it is breaking the command into 2 parts , like this
[image: screen shot]

```
scp KB_33.txt sjain@$X.X.X.X
:/home/sjain
```

And when I am directly hardcoding the value instead of destIP  , it is working fine.

How can I fix this?

**Input CSV file Data**

```
10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your csv files for me to test.

Comment: Updated the question , it contains only 1 row

Comment: If it contains just one row, reading it in a while loop is overkill, just use `cut` command and pipe.

Comment: in future it will have more rows , for now I have just put for testing purpose

Comment: I haven't tested this, but do try tr-ing ',' to ' ' and don't use IFS. I'm not sure about the scope in this case, it might mess up the parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you split the contents of your CSV file you're splitting on commas, `,`. This can be problematic because the second IP address in that file likely has a trailing newline character after it.

The easiest method to resolve this would be to simply chomp that character off the end of the `$destIP` variable like so:

```
export sourceIP=$f1
export destIP=$(echo "$f2" | tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: Yes, you were right second IP address has the trailing new lien character in it. - Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`echo` normally puts a newline after printing its arguments. You can prevent it
from doing so by using

```
echo -n "Destination IP Address: $destIP"
```

to strip the `$destIP` you could try:

```
export destIP=$(echo $f2)
```

Comment: dats correct , but actual problem is at this line `scp KB_33.txt sjain@$destIP:/home/sjain` , here it is splitting into 2 lines after variable destIP.

Comment: Sorry I should have read further. I have updated the answer

Comment: thanks anthon , i tried it but still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr` to delete the newline character. In place of `sjain@$destIP`, use:

```
sjain@$(echo $destIP | tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: i tried this 
`scp KB_33.txt sjain@$(echo $destIP | tr -d '\n'):/home/sjain`
but it didn't work

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $destIP` and `echo $(echo $destIP | tr -d '\n')`

Comment: #echo $destIP

[sjain@XYZ ~]$ echo "Destination IP Address234: 10.X.X.X
> "
Destination IP Address234: 10.X.X.X

#echo $(echo $destIP | tr -d '\n')
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ echo "Dest 2 :" 10.X.X.X
Dest 2 : 10.X.X.X
[sjain@XYZ ~]$